# Как добавить кнопки в сообщение slack используя laravel

Tags: php, laravel, уведомления, slack

Есть локальный сервис фирмы, на котором можно взять отпуск на роботе. Когда пользователь выбрал даты и отправляет форму то данные сохраняются в базу данных и отправляется уведомление для администратора в Slack. Нужно сделать интерактивные кнопки подтверждения и отмены которые будут отправлять запрос на сервер, и после ответа сервера выводить статут отпуска вместо кнопок.
Я уже второй день не могу решить эту проблему...
[image: сообщение в slack]

Код уведомления:

```
/**
 * Получить представление Slack-уведомления.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return SlackMessage
 */
public function toSlack($notifiable)
{
    $url_accept = URL::signedRoute('vacation_accept', ['vacation_id' => $this->vacation_id]);
    $url_cancel = URL::signedRoute('vacation_cancel', ['vacation_id' => $this->vacation_id]);
    
        
        return (new SlackMessage())
            ->attachment( function ($attachment) use ($url_accept, $url_cancel) {
               $attachment->title($this->user->name . " "  . $this->user->surname . " хочет взять отпуск")
                   ->fields([
                       "На период:" => $this->from_date->format('d.m.Y') . " - " . $this->to_date->format('d.m.Y'),
                       "Количество дней:" => $this->days,
                       "Запрос отправлен:" => "Mar 10, 2021",
                       "Причина:" => $this->reason,
                       "За счет:" => "Company",
                   ])
                   ->content("<" . $url_accept ."|*Accept*> - " . "<" . $url_cancel ."|*Cancel*>")
               ->markdown(['text']);
            }); }
```